# How to access angular 6 application from other machine?

Tags: node.js, angular, ubuntu-16.04, angular6, angular-cli-v6

I installed Angular 6, that runs in my local machine. But not run another machine which is connected local network. I have tried these steps but not use.

```
ng serve --host 10.0.136.126 // http://10.0.136.126:4200
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 // http://10.0.136.126:4200
ng serve --host=0.0.0.0 // http://10.0.136.126:4200
ng serve --host=0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check // http://10.0.136.126:4200
ng serve --host 10.0.136.126 --disable-host-check // http://10.0.136.126:4200
```

Above command is working fine in my machine but not in my colleague machine which is connected local network.
I'm using *ubuntu 16.04*, tested with both ubuntu and windows machine.
Versions:

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 8.11.3
OS: linux x64
Angular: 6.0.4

node --version => 6.1.0
npm --version => 8.11.3
```

But I can access my phpmyadmin or any php project with http://10.0.136.126/phpmyadmin in other machine.

Comment: Make sure your firewall isn't blocking port 4200

Answer (score 2):

Yes the culprit is firewall with port number in ubuntu 16.04 machine. Have to check the firewall. And add port number by

```
sudo ufw allow 4200/tcp
```

Answer (score 0):

If your are accessing your php-projects and phpMyAdmin this means there is already a server running.

So in order to use your angular project you can easily deploy on the server.

1. run `ng build --base-herf .`   `// dont forget the dot`
2. copy the dist folder to the server's www folder.

   - if you are using apache copy the dist folder and past it in the /var/www/html

Then you can access your angular project http://10.0.136.126/dist

Let me know if this helps or not.

Comment: not its in dev mode,I want to access with ip:4200 only.